# Wildfly 10 - XNIO WorkerThread (default I/O-x) with 100% CPU usage

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, wildfly, wildfly-10

We are changing our cluster topology and facing a 100% CPU issue in the "default I/O-x" thread (org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread).

Looks like an infinity loop in the ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(..) but I'm not sure about it.

The problem is intermittent and not simple to reproduce, and it needs a restart to stop.

Every time that it enters this state, the thread dump is the same:

```
"default I/O-2" #103 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd0f83a4800 nid=0x6941 runnable [0x00007fd0e9be0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:783)
- locked <0x00000007a2be6ec0> (a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)
at java.lang.Throwable.(Throwable.java:250)
at java.lang.Exception.(Exception.java:54)
at java.io.IOException.(IOException.java:47)
at java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.(ClosedChannelException.java:52)
at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit.write(JsseStreamConduit.java:1022)
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.write(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:150)
at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$StringWriteListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:385)
at org.xnio.http.HttpUpgrade$HttpUpgradeState$StringWriteListener.handleEvent(HttpUpgrade.java:372)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.conduits.WriteReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.writeReady(WriteReadyHandler.java:65)
at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit.run(JsseStreamConduit.java:393)
at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit.writeReady(JsseStreamConduit.java:524)
at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit$1.writeReady(JsseStreamConduit.java:287)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:94)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
```

The change in the topology is adding a few more servers groups and changes the reverse proxy (nginx) in order to redirect (status 301) every http connection to https.

Analyzing the thread dump, seems to be something related to https (package org.xnio.ssl.*), **but everything behind the nginx is plain http.**

Our application provides a Websocket endpoint (WSS through nginx) and makes a lot of EJB remote invocations to others servers (http-remoting, directly to the other server without passing through nginx).

Also, the application make/receive some REST calls (RESTEasy) to others servers in the cluster through the load balancer (nginx https, in order to avoid the 301 redirection)

What could be causing this?

thanks!

Comment: Could you solve your problem and if so how?

Comment: @Lonzak no solution. I think is related with HA-full profile, because the problem began when I changed to this profile. Back to standalone-full and the problem gone.